# How to create connection string for SQL Server 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my connection string.

```
Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2012; Initial Catalog=admissio; Integrated Security=False; User ID=amedb; Password=*******; server=66.7.223.250;
```

I am trying to connect to a database but I'm unable to do so. Also I changed `Data Source=66.7.233.250,8880;` or `server=66.7.233.250:8880; or server=66.7.233.250,8880;`

Is any other way to connect database?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Why do you use `server` at all, when you ask to connect to a *local* database? Are you trying to connect to a named instance called `MSSQLSERVER2012` on your local machine or a database on a remote server with IP `66.7.233.250` ?

Comment: Instead of writing the connection string by hand, add a Connection String setting in the project's `Settings` tab and edit it. This will display the connection dialog box that allows you to pick server, database, user *and* test the connection

Comment: You cannot have `Data Source=` **and** `server=` at the same time - these are **synonyms** - you need to use one or the other - but not both together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Data Source=66.7.223.250; Initial Catalog=admissio; Integrated Security=False; User ID=amedb; Password=*******;
```

or

```
Data Source=66.7.223.250\MSSQLSERVER2012; Initial Catalog=admissio; Integrated Security=False; User ID=amedb; Password=*******;
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: that is not correct - the default SQL Server service name for the default (unnamed) instance is always **MSSQLSERVER** (without any version numbers or anything)

Comment: @marc_s oops, you are right. I never use such names for named instances so I got confused.